# Null pointer exception in eclipse while programming for android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I know the question is a bit simplistic, but I feel like I'm missing something big and obvious.  I am following the tutorial for graphics handling in android from ( http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-vi,209.html ).  When I look at logcat, it tells me a line number where it thinks the null pointer exception came from)  When I replace the numbers that are pulled from classes there with constants, the null pointer exception just moves somewhere else in the program.

Is there some way in the eclipse debugger to identify what specific pointer it views as the one that is null when it shouldn't be?  I get the null pointer exception, and that's all it will say, that there's an exception, but no information on what pointer is supposedly null.

Also, when I try to put in breakpoints for testing, while I can get the debugger to come up and stop at the breakpoint, logcat shows that a null pointer exception has still been thrown, even though the breakpoint should be hit before the part causing the exception comes up.  Why are breakpoints being ignored?

Comment: You can either step through the code with the Eclipse debugger, checking to see what variable is null, or you can use a println statement(s) placed above the error to see what variable is in fact null.

Comment: LogCat should say the line the NullPointerException occurred. Unless you have tens or hundreds of objects in a line of code, it should be easy to track down which one is null.

Comment: There is no way in the default debugger to simply see what it thought was null?  This seems like a huge oversight in debugging interfaces, so there must be a reason if there is no way to simply store the call that caused the exception to show to the developer.

Comment: The line from the tutorial was:  _currentGraphic.getCoordinates().setX((int) event.getX() - _currentGraphic.getGraphic().getWidth() / 2);  So I can see at least 3 places that a null pointer exception could come from, and when i replace the values inside the setX() block with a constant, the exception just jumps to another point in the code, making it more difficult to track its source.

Comment: The Eclipse debugger will show what is null if you step through your code at this point and watch the significant variables. I see no oversight at all.

Comment: It just seems like that if there is an error, that the variables section of the debugger could say, have a flag displayed next to the variable that caused the error, or something listed in the thread tracking box could mention which specific call caused the exception.  This seems like an understandable feature of a debugger.

Comment: What you want to do is catch the error _before_ it occurs, i.e. set the breakpoint early enough in the method throwing the exception so that you can inspect your variables and see which one is null. For instance, if there's a line with, say, `someVariable.getStuff().doSomething()`, and you're getting a NPE on that line, then either `someVariable` is null or `someVariable.getStuff()` returns null, so `doSomething()` will be invoked on null. The Eclipse debugger lets you select `someVariable.doStuff()` to right-click and inspect its value at runtime. Seem like a great feature of a debugger? ;-)

Comment: Part of my problem is that breakpoints don't seem to work... entirely.  I can set one, and on the debug screen it shows me stop there, but logcat still displays information about the null pointer exception on a line that I haven't executed yet according to the debugger.  Also, animations still are running on my android emulator, so obviously some aspect of the system is still running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some way in the eclipse debugger to identify what specific pointer it views as the one that is null when it shouldn't be?

The answer here is Yes and No. **No:** You cannot tell Eclipse to specify which pointer to check for null at. All you can do is watch the pointers themselves when you are broken in the class or function. **Yes:** All you have to do is split up your calls and you can find the object. For instance, the code in question *seems* to be:

```
_currentGraphic.getCoordinates().setX((int) event.getX() - _currentGraphic.getGraphic().getWidth() / 2);
```

You would split this up into (forgive the pseudo, but I don't know which types you are working with):

```
Type _coords = _currentGraphic.getCoordinates();
Type _graphic = _currentGraphic.getGraphic();
Type _width = _graphic.getWidth();

_coords.setX((int) event.getX() - _width / 2);
```

Now, the line of code is broken up into one object per line, easily able to determine which is the offender.

> Why are breakpoints being ignored?

This one is a bit more complicated. Your breakpoints may or may not be being ignored. In general, if you are getting to one breakpoint, it should be getting to all of them in order. However, I have noticed, in Eclipse, that sometimes breakpoints are ignored given certain circumstances. For some reason, the adb is not completely integrated with the Eclipse debugger. This means that if you change breakpoints in the middle of a currently running debug, it may or may not recognize them. Often it is enough to kill the app completely and redebug it.

Additionally, sometimes the adb and debugger do not synchronize correctly. There is a command that you can use (best at the beginning of your code) that helps that along quite nicely. If you insert the command `Debug.waitForDebugger()`, the synchronization will come into place allowing the earliest breakpoints (those in your first onCreate() and similar) to work correctly. The command does make you debugging much slower though. Using this at key points will also mitigate the blatant breakpoint ignoring discussed previously.

Now it is important to note that just because you think it is ignoring them, does not mean it is. Sometimes (especially with Android, right now), execution does not necessarily go through the paths the developer thinks that it does. For instance, one might set a breakpoint in the `ViewClass(Context context)` constructor, when it is actually created via XML with the `ViewClass(Context context, AttributeSet attr)` constructor. Heck, even a forgotten creation of an object can completely steer execution in the wrong way. This may be especially true if the object has `static` members or code that is run on **class** initialization (not **object** initialization). Without looking at your code, I cannot say which is happening, but hopefully this gives you the tools to find your answer.

Hope this helps,

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: Thank you for this response.  Due to it being a tutorial, it had the correct source code available that works (seperate from the walkthrough discussion of the tutorial) and I found the errors.  One was ignoring something in the tutorial that was small in type, but big in implications, the other was something that the tutorial author forgot to put into the tutorial explanation at all, but had in the main source code.  But this was definitely a great answer, particularly for your explanation on the breakpoints issue.  Thanks

Comment: Gotta love it when a tutorial has the correct working code separated from the walkthrough. :) Makes things loads of fun!